# Heat equation, $Q=msdtT$ during fusion and vaporization

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-transition

We know that the heat supplied is directly proportional to the change in temperature. But during fusion and vaporization, the temperature is the same i.e $d T=0$. Is the equation invalid in these process?

Comment: Yes, the equation is valid for a single phase, but not for a phase change (unless you assume that the heat capacity is a delta function at the phase change).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. There is instead a substance-specific "enthalpy of fusion" to account for the heat gained/lost during the constant-temperature phase change.